# How to display feature names in sklearn decision tree?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I've currently got a decision tree displaying the features names as `X[index]`, i.e. `X[0], X[1], X[2]`, etc.

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

 
# plot tree
plt.figure(figsize=(20,16))# set plot size (denoted in inches)
tree.plot_tree(dt,fontsize=10)
```

Im looking to replace these X[featureNumber] with the actual feature name.

so instead of it displaying X[0], I would want it to display the feature name returned by `X.columns.values[0]` (I don't know if this code is correct).

Im also aware there is an easy way of doing this using graphviz, but for some reason I cant get graphviz running in Jupiter, so Im looking for a way of doing it without.

Photo of current decision tree:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is explained in [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html):

> `sklearn.tree.plot_tree(decision_tree, *, max_depth=None, feature_names=None, class_names=None, label='all', filled=False, impurity=True, node_ids=False, proportion=False, rotate='deprecated', rounded=False, precision=3, ax=None, fontsize=None)`
>
> `feature_names`: list of strings, default=`None`
>
> Names of each of the features. If `None`, generic names will be used (“X[0]”, “X[1]”, …).