# Name of variables in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I need to use DecisionTreeClassifier from sklearn library. There are multiple columns in my dataset
which I have to dummy. My problem is that I have variable names in the resulting models
non-speaking names of feature_1, feature_2, ..., feature_n. How do I give them real names? I work with a dataset with about 400 columns, so manual renaming is not an ideal way. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from yellowbrick.model_selection import RFECV


raw_data = {'sum': [2345, 256,  43, 643, 34 , 23, 95], 
        'department': ['a1', 'a1', 'a3', 'a3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2'],
        'sex': ['m', 'neudane', 'f', '', 'f', 'f', 'f']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['sum', 'department', 'sex'])

y = {'y': ['cat_a', 'cat_a', 'cat_b', 'cat_c', 'cat_b', 'cat_a', 'cat_a']}

y = pd.DataFrame(y, columns = ['y'])


categorical = ['department', 'sex']

numerical = ['sum']


X = df[categorical + numerical]


categorical_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
    ("encoder", OneHotEncoder(sparse=True, handle_unknown="ignore"))
])

numerical_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")),
    ("scaler", StandardScaler())
])



basic_preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
    #("nominal_preprocessor", nominal_pipeline, nominal),
    ("categorical_preprocessor", categorical_pipeline, categorical),
    ("numerical_preprocessor", numerical_pipeline, numerical)
])


preprocessed = basic_preprocessor.fit_transform(X)


X = preprocessed


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import export_text
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(train, y_train)


r = export_text(clf)
print(r)



>>>r = export_text(clf)
>>>print(r)
|--- feature_1 <= 0.50
|   |--- feature_7 <= -0.19
|   |   |--- class: cat_b
|   |--- feature_7 >  -0.19
|   |   |--- class: cat_c
|--- feature_1 >  0.50
|   |--- class: cat_a
```

Answer (score 3):

Two key components can help make this work.  The first gets the encoding names from the `OneHotEncoder`:  `OneHotEncoder.get_feature_names_out`.  Specifically, you use that on your `encoder` as `encoder.get_feature_names_out()`.  The second component is that `sklearn.tree.export_text` takes a `feature_names` argument.  So, you can pass those extracted names right into the display system.  Other `sklearn` tree displayers also take that parameter (`plot_tree`, `export_graphviz`).

See here for related SO:

1. [Feature names from OneHotEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570947/feature-names-from-onehotencoder)
2. [How to display feature names in sklearn decision tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552426/how-to-display-feature-names-in-sklearn-decision-tree)

`sklearn` docs here:

1. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html
2. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.tree (follow those links for the tree export/plot functions).

The following should work for you (Edit:  I forget the pipeline part in my example.  You can use `my_pipe.named_steps[step_name]` to extract out the `OneHotEncoder`.  You may have to nest that since you have nested pipelines.  Added that example below.):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_text

import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)  # ---> 1.0.2 for me

ftrs = pd.DataFrame({'Sex'     : ['male', 'female']*3, 
                     'AgeGroup': ['0-20', '0-20', 
                                  '20-60', '20-60',
                                  '80+', '80+']})
tgt  = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
enc_ftrs = encoder.fit_transform(ftrs)
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(enc_ftrs, tgt)

encoder_names = encoder.get_feature_names_out()
print(export_text(dtc, feature_names = list(encoder_names)))
```

Which for me gives the following output:

```
|--- AgeGroup_80+ <= 0.50
|   |--- class: 1
|--- AgeGroup_80+ >  0.50
|   |--- Sex_female <= 0.50
|   |   |--- class: 0
|   |--- Sex_female >  0.50
|   |   |--- class: 1
```

Including the pipeline, it looks like this:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('enc', OneHotEncoder()),
                 ('dtc', DecisionTreeClassifier())])
pipe.fit(ftrs, tgt)
feature_names = list(pipe.named_steps['enc'].get_feature_names_out())
print(export_text(pipe.named_steps['dtc'],
                  feature_names = feature_names))
```

with the same output.